# Interaction of the magnetic bubbles at the edge of the heliosphere and the Earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, solar-system

I'm going to ask about if there is some effect/interaction of the magnetic bubbles that are explained in [1] from YouTube **and** the Earth's magnetic field. I know these subjects from an informative point of view. I refer (as reference for all users) the existence of such magnetic bubbles at Solar System's edge, as [1], and that I know also the Wikipedia [*Earth's magnetic field*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field) from which I evoke that maybe should be some interaction between these magnetic fields.

> **Question.** Is it possible to say anything about this interaction, the physics of this interaction? If you think that it should be a despicable interaction, please explain why. **Many thanks.**

I hope that it is possible say something about it (I evoke what work can be done to elucidate something about my question). I know that the field lines extend over all space-time, but I suppose that if both magnetic fields are very far, then should be some easy explanation about the interaction is despicable. Can be done any computations/models to justify it? I've known in the past the standard exercises of courses of high school or a first course of physics for mathematicians, but I think that the distribution of these magnetic fields are more complicated.

I add this additional comment to emphasize that the context or scenario for both magnetic fields is that of **standard physics and standard events that can happen**. In your explanation, if my post is worth of the site, you can do those simplifications/assumptions that you think are reasonable for your explanations and computations.

### References:

[1] *NASA |Voyager Finds Magnetic Bubbles at Solar System's Edge*, from the official channel **NASA Goddard** of YouTube (June, 9th 2011).

Comment: I'm asking if it is possible to quantify this interaction from your model and reasonings. If the question is easy, or doesn't contain enough physical content to made of this post an interesting post, feel free to comment it, with the purpose to delete the post. Many thanks again for the patience and attention of all users.

Comment: I add this addtional comment, the context or scenario for both magnetic fields is that of **standard physics and standard events that can happen**. In your explanation, if my post is worth of the site, you can do those simplifications/assumptions that you think are reasonable for your exaplanations and computations.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the edit @Qmechanic I feel that my question was not the best. I'm going to wait if there is more feedback thanking to the user who answered the question, in the hope that the resulting post (question and answer) can to improve the content of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything at the edge of the solar system is much to far away to be effected by the earth's magnetic dipole field which drops off (at a distance) with the cube of the distance.

Comment: Many thanks I'm going to wait some weeks if there are more contributions before I'm accepting an answer. Many thanks for your answer and attention.

Comment: I'm going to accept the answer, the problem here is that my question isn't the best. I've thought about how I could improve this post in the future, if adding a secondary question or offering a bounty to draw more attention (I emphasize that the problem is in my question, not in your anwer), but at this date I think that the fair thing is accept it. Many thanks again.